# Google map v2 Heatmap population

Tags: android, google-maps, heatmap, google-maps-api-2

Would it be possible to use a heat map to represent/show the amount of people in the specific area using google map v2?

If not , would there be other library or API that I can use to know represent the amount of people in the area.

reference that I saw on the internet: http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com/2014/02/population-mapping.html

Comment: A heat map is a UI representation of data. You build a heat map from data, not the other way around. Are you asking 1) for an API to determine amount of people in an area 2) for a way to build a heat map in Google Maps v2 for Android? Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: 1.) Yes, An api to determine the amount of people in an area. 2.) I want to represent the amount of people using Heatmap in google map v2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey here is the example how you can use heatmap and show your max population

Add all marker in your map then use this code.

```
HeatmapTileProvider mProvider;
TileOverlay mOverlay;
// Add your all lat lng inside this array list and pass it to addHeatMap
List<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

double puLat = 0, puLng = 0;



    private void createMarker() {
    double cLat, cLng;
    cLat = locationCur.getLatitude();
    cLng = locationCur.getLongitude();

    Marker testMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(cLat, cLng)).draggable(true)
            .title("Demanding Areas").flat(false));

    testMarker.showInfoWindow();

   }

    private void addHeatMap() {


    mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder().data(list).build();
    mOverlay = googleMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions()
            .tileProvider(mProvider));
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: This is helpful, but i'm looking for something that is automated, It's like when i open my app , it will automatically show up the heatmap  in my may map that indicates the amount of user on the specific area, Would this be possible using google map v2?

Comment: Nothing is automated. Atleast you need to pass values and open Google Map then heapmap will work.